# Force page to load from server - not from cache, using javascript or meta

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I have completed google searching on a good solution....

I need to load the page from the server each time it is called - NOT from the cache.

I've tried the solution of adding the date to the url of the page being called, but it seems to be having some negative effect on the cookies and querystring.

I am currently looking at using a set of meta tags.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

But i have read that i should not use this in production (not sure why).

Does anyone have any other ideas to ensure i am loading the page from the server each time and not from the cache?

Comment: Can you cite where you found that using meta tags are bad for production? The only other alternative (that I'm aware of), without using a "nonce"  value (like a date), is to set this information in the response headers.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2286580

Comment: It's unclear why you would want to remove the meta tags in production, unless of course you want the page to be cached in production. Are you expecting the page to be cached in a production environment? If not, then you should use the meta tags/response headers/nonce value to prevent the caching.